# Bug In isConnected method for graphs

Tags: java, recursion, graph

I am trying to build a method that returns a boolean response to verify whether my graph is connected or not. The graph is made up of vertices and contains an arraylist of all vertices known as vertexList. Every vertex can have up to 4 edges. To return an arraylist of all edges there is the getNeighbors() method:

```
public boolean isConnected(){
    this.unmarkAllVertices();
    Vertex rootV = this.vertexList.get(0);
    visit(rootV);
    int unmarkedVertices = 0;
    for (Vertex element : this.vertexList) {
        if (element.getMarked() == false) {
            unmarkedVertices++;
        }
    }
    if (unmarkedVertices > 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

private void visit(Vertex v) {
    if (v.getMarked() == true) {
        return;
    } else {
        v.setMarked(true);
        for (Vertex n : v.getNeighbors()) {
            if (n != null) {
                visit(n);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Can you find the bug or should this work theoretically?

Comment: Conceptually speaking this algorithm looks correct. Can you provide more code - say, for `unmarkAllVertices()`, `getMarked()`, and `setMarked(boolean)?`

Comment: public void unmarkAll(){
  for (Vertex v : this.vertexList) {
   v.setMarked(false);
  }
 }

Comment: public boolean getMarked() {
  return this.marked;
 }

Comment: public void setMarked(boolean m){
  this.marked = m;
 }

Comment: How do you know this isn't working? Do you have a test case it's failing?